# Cannot use string(size_t , char) constructor

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constructor

I have a class `Screen` which has member content initialized using `std::string(size_t, char)` constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Screen {
    friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os ,const Screen& screen);

    Screen() = default;
    Screen(std::size_t w, std::size_t h) :
    width(w), height(h), content(w * h , ' ') {}

    Screen(std::size_t w, std::size_t h, char c) :
    width(w), height(h), content(w * h, c) {}

private:
    std::size_t width = 24;
    std::size_t height = 80;
    std::size_t cursor = 0;
    std::string content(width * height, ' ');
};
```

I tried declaring a string in similar way inside main but I get the same error, I am not able to figure out what am I doing wrong here.

```
structures.cpp:15:25: error: 'width' is not a type
     std::string content(width * height , ' ');
                         ^
structures.cpp:15:42: error: expected identifier before '\x20'
     std::string content(width * height , ' ');
                                          ^
structures.cpp:15:42: error: expected ',' or '...' before '\x20'
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using the initializer list to construct the `std::string`?  What purpose does it serve to attempt to initialize where you declared your string here `string content( (width * height), ' ');`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following fixes your code. I guess a little disambiguation between a member function declaration and a member data definition was needed:

```
std::string content = std::string(width * height, ' ');
```

But what I'd do instead of repeating myself in constructors is to use delegating constructor and a default argument:

```
struct Screen
{
    Screen(std::size_t w, std::size_t h, char c = ' ') :
    width(w),
    height(h),
    content(w * h, c)
    {}

    Screen() :
    Screen(24, 80)
    {}

private:
    std::size_t width;
    std::size_t height;
    std::string content;
};
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used this syntax but it appears you can initialize std::string inside class body as follows:

```
 std::size_t width = 24;
 std::size_t height = 80;
 std::size_t cursor = 0;
 std::string content{std::string( (width * height), ' ')};
```

you should remember to keep order of initialization as above.

The problem with your code is that if you initialize `content` in constructors  initialization list, then compiler will not perform initialization which is at your variable definition. So - as you said in one comment - you cannot do default initialization and then overwrite it in constructor.